# How to connect custom collectionviewCell to reuseidentifier with XIB - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xib, collectionview, reuseidentifier

I am making a custom collectionview cell Using XIB.

The collectionview is placed inside an viewController as an extension.

This is the code i am using to call the Xib View but i get an error telling me i need to use reuseidentifier. But i have no clue how to use that while using XIB.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomCell

        return cell
    }
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a reuseIdentifier for your cell. Lets create it based on your collectionViewCell class name. Declare reuseId, in your ViewController file:

```
let reuseId = String(describing: CustomCell.self)
```

You need to register your cell to your collectionView in viewDidLoad method.

```
collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseId)
```

Then in your `cellForItemAt` method:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId, for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
//return cell, or update cell elements first.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the `CustomCell` like,

```
let customCellNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: .main)
collectionView.register(customCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

And use the same registered cell in `cellForItemAt` like,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Tank you for your answer. I have another question.
What if i have 2 different customCell? let say CustomCell1 and CustomCell2.
How do i register them?

Comment: same `let customCellNib1 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell1", bundle: .main)
collectionView.register(customCellNib1, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")`

`let customCellNib2 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell2", bundle: .main)
collectionView.register(customCellNib2, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")`

And based on your requirement or logic the same specific cell should be returned in  `cellForItemAt` delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 4.0 and 4.2**

In your **viewDidLoad**:

*custom collectionViewCell*

```
mainCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "your_custom_cell_name", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "your_custom_cell_identifier")
```

In cellForItemAt indexPath:

```
let cell : <your_custom_cell_name> = mainCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "your_custom_cell_identifier", for: indexPath) as! <your_custom_cell_name>
```

And don't forget to set identifier for your custom cell in xib section.